# C# Error in calendar after upgrading project .net target framework from 3.5 to 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, ambiguous, ambiguous-call

I have the below function of buildculture for calendar:

```
private void buildCulture(string culture, string calendarType)
{

    CultureInfo ci=null;
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {
                ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            }
        }

        // Calendar is from system.windows.control.calendar, 
        // ci is from system.globalization.calendar:
        Calendar originalCal = ci.Calendar;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture) || 
             originalCal.ToString().Replace("System.Globalization.", "") != culture)
        {
            foreach (Calendar supportCal in ci.OptionalCalendars)
            {
                if (calendarType == 
                      supportCal.ToString().Replace("System.Globalization.", ""))
                {
                    ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = supportCal;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function still work in .net version 3.5. But after I upgrade to .net 4.5, there's an error appear for line `Calendar originalCal = ci.Calendar` which says: `Calendar is an ambiguous reference between system.windows.control.calendar and system globalization.calendar`.

How do we fix this guys?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the either the fully qualified name when declaring the object, like so:

```
System.Globalization.Calendar originalCal = ci.Calendar;
```

Or, if you know you aren't using the `System.Windows.Control.Calendar` type, you can alias the type `Calendar` to the one in `System.Globalization` with the following `using`:

```
using Calendar = System.Globalization.Calendar;
```

Comment: I'm not sure which class to use. Is there any difference between system.windows.control.calendar and system.globalization.calendar?

Comment: @Coolguy There is. You're certainly using the `System.Globalization.Calendar` in this case. The question is whether or not you're also using a `System.Windows.Control.Calendar` control in your application. If you are, then `using Calendar = System.Globalization.Calendar` would cause a different compilation error, stating that there was no implicit conversion from `System.Windows.Control.Calendar` to `System.Globalization.Calendar`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, `system.globalization.calendar` is probably what you want to use, since you seem to be working with the format of dates.

`system.windows.control.calendar` does not contain calendar *data*, but rather a calendar *control* - the graphics rendered as a calendar that is.

To achieve this, either remove any `import` statement that references `system.windows.control.calendar`.

If that is not possible (if you're using something else under `System.windows.control`, so `Calendar` gets included implicitly), then declare an *alias* for the `system.globalization` namespace:

```
using glob = System.Globalization;
```

This defines `glob` as short for the namespace `System.Globalization`, and this will allow you to refer to the correct Calendar class as follows:

```
var ci = new glob.CultureInfo(culture);
glob.Calendar myCal = ci.Calendar;
```

---

*PS: You could shorten it even more if you wanted to, but personally, I think anything shorter than `glob` will make it's meaning less clear.*